# Main Window Goes Blank

Tags: qt, qml

In my QMainWindow based application, I'm using two **QQuickWidgets**. One loads the map (using **QML Map Type**)  and other one loads a custom scene. MainWindow also runs a **QTimer** at 10 Hz.

When I continuously zoom in/out on the map, at some point, the main window goes blank. This behavior is quite consistent. After resizing the main window, it gets refreshed but sometimes the qml scene is not rendered properly. Kindly have a look at the attached screenshots.

Why the main window goes blank and how to overcome it.

You can find working demo application on GitHub: [github link](https://github.com/aamirglb/Demo.git)

I'm using **Desktop Qt 5.12.3 MinGW 64-bit**.

Working App

[image]

Blank Main Window

[image]

Corrupted QML Scene

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce (Suse Linux + Qt5.14.1).

Comment: do you mean demo application works fine under Suse Linux + Qt5.14.1?

Comment: Yes.  That appears to be the case.  Certainly no blank/black map window or badly rendered qml widget.

Comment: Can't reproduce as well (XUbuntu 22.04 + Qt 5.15.3). You should probably debug `bracketview.qml`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html#details:

> Note: The utilization of QQuickWidget deactivates the threaded render
> loop across all platforms. Consequently, certain advantages associated
> with threaded rendering, such as Animator classes and vsync-driven
> animations, will not be accessible.

It is suggested that you consider using QQuickView instead of QQuickWidget. Here is an example and a conceptual representation:

```
quickView = new QQuickView();
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(quickView);
ui.verticalLayout->addWidget(container);
```